# Setting Width and Height of a Wix Dialog based on some property

Tags: dynamic, dialog, wix, height

I have created a dialog in my Wix Project.
I want to change the Width and Height of that dialog based on some property.
I have done this:-

```
  <Property Id="PROPERTY_WIDTH" Value="2875"/>
  <Property Id="PROPERTY_HEIGHT" Value="1568"/>
  <Dialog Id="DIALOGID" Title="TITLETEXT" NoMinimize="SETYESORNO" Width="
  [PROPERTY_WIDTH]" Height="[PROPERTY_HEIGHT]">
```

But this gives an error:-

Error   156 The Dialog/@Width attribute's value, '[PROPERTY_WIDTH]', is not a legal integer value.  Legal integer values are from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Error   157 The Dialog/@Height attribute's value, '[PROPERTY_HEIGHT]', is not a legal integer value.  Legal integer values are from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.